# MS Excel: remove number of characters after a specific character in a string

Tags: excel, excel-formula, excel-2010

I have a column with values like

> WI60P-14E64F5167E6-01138

or

> WI60-34D03E185267-01051

etc....

i need to find the first occurrence of `-` till the second occurrence of `-` and remove the resulting character.

I am using this function `=MID(A1,FIND("-",A1),13)` which returns me `-34D03E185267` or `-14E64F5167E6` from the above strings.

But I want the output like **WI60P-01138** or **WI60-01051**

Can anyone help me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming that the length of text between the two hyphens never varies, you can use your existing function, along with `SUBSTITUTE` to get the desired string, like so:

```
=SUBSTITUTE(A1,MID(A1,FIND("-",A1),13),"")
```

Alternately, you can use `FIND` to get the hyphen positions and again use `SUBSTITUTE` to get the replaced string, like so:

```
=SUBSTITUTE(A1,MID(A1,FIND("-",A1),FIND("-",A1,FIND("-",A1)+1)-FIND("-",A1)),"")
```

Notice that one of the `FIND` expressions takes 3 parameters - by passing `FIND("-",A1) + 1` as the third parameter, we get the second occurence of '-' within the cell.

Answer (score 0):

This will work for any position of the two hyphens:

```
=CONCATENATE(MID(A1;FIND("-";A1)+1;FIND("-";A1;FIND("-";A1)+1)-FIND("-";A1)-1))
```

Answer (score 0):

### Solution using multiple cells as support (with dynamic length of the string):

Put this in cell `B1` to obtain the first part of the code:

```
=MID(A1,1,FIND("-",A1)-1)
```

Put this in cell `C1` to obtain the last part of the code:

```
=MID(A1,FIND("-",A1)+1,LEN(A1))
```

Put this in cell `D1` to concatenate both and get your result:

```
=concat(B1,C1)
```

### Solution in a single cell (with dynamic length of the string)

Put this in cell `B1` to get the same result as above :

```
=concat(MID(A1,1,FIND("-",A1)-1),MID(MID(A1,FIND("-",A1)+1,LEN(A1)),FIND("-",MID(A1,FIND("-",A1)+1,LEN(A1))),LEN(MID(A1,FIND("-",A1)+1,LEN(A1)))))
```